# Not all data being imported to Access from CSV file in VBA

Tags: vba, csv

I've been tasked with creating a macro that will download information from another website as a csv file and save it into Access.

The issue I am having is that not all the data is being imported into Access. Each time the macro runs data will be imported into the Access table, but some data will be missing completely, and there are many 'Type Conversation Failure' and 'Truncated Failure' errors.

Ultimately the data appears to be fine in the Access table except in one specific field. The data can contain anything from a word, a sentence, a letter, a number, or nothing at all, but only numeric values will display in the field. Yet there are other fields in the table with a similar mish-mash of data that load fine.

All the fields are set to Long Text. I don't understand why in only a single field will only numeric values be imported despite being a Long Text field.

Here is the code I have so far

```
Sub FindFileAndFormatIt()

'Creating variables
Dim fileSysObj As FileSystemObject
Dim File As Object
Dim Folder
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileDate As Date
Dim uniqueID As String
Dim txtFileContent As String
Dim txtFileNumber As Integer

'File directory (dir)
Const myDir As String = "a folder"

Set fileSysObj = New FileSystemObject
Set Folder = fileSysObj.GetFolder(myDir)

'Looping through all files to find the newest CSV file
fileDate = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
For Each File In Folder.Files
    If InStr(1, File.Name, ".CSV") > 0 Then
        If File.DateLastModified > fileDate Then
            fileDate = File.DateLastModified               
            filePath = File.Path
        End If
    End If
Next File

'Ending the file scripting
Set fileSysObj = Nothing
Set Folder = Nothing

'Determine the file number available for use by the FileOpen function
txtFileNumber = FreeFile

'Open file in a read state
Open filePath For Input As txtFileNumber

'Getting file content
txtFileContent = Input(LOF(txtFileNumber), txtFileNumber)

'Close file
Close txtFileNumber

'Replace column titles with titles under 64 characters
' A whole bunch of txtFileContent = Replace(...)

'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function
txtFileNumber = FreeFile

'Open file in an edit state
Open filePath For Output As txtFileNumber

'Write new text data to file
Print #txtFileNumber, txtFileContent

'Close the file
Close txtFileNumber

'Import text file into Access
DoCmd.TransferText acTextTransfer, , "CustomerSurvey", filePath, True

End Sub
```

@ Davey C

Here are two screenshots of the CSV file as text

Screenshot 1

[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2 - the titles are really long

[image: Screenshot 2 - the titles are really long]

@ Davey C

Here are the headers of the CSV file. Any non-numeric data in the boldfaced header is not being imported into Access (the first three rows are non-numeric and are left blank)

JobNo,InvDate,StoreName,Address,"LCL: Satisfied with accuracy? ","LCL: Comments for Improvement ",LCL: General comments ,"LCL: 1-5 Rate of backroom preparation ","LCL: 1-5 Rate of salesfloor preparation ","LCL: 1-5 Rate of WIS service ",LCL: Received pre inventory call from WIS? ,LCL: Count completed within the count window? ,**LCL: All WIS counters present at start of count?** ,"LCL: Rechecks completed and copies retained during count? ",LCL: Improvement areas for next count? ,Name of LCL Manager completing the survey: ,Name of WIS MOR: ,WIS: Store rep lay tags and identified product to be counted? ,"WIS: Comments for improvement ",WIS: General comments ,"WIS: 1-5 Rate of backroom preparation ","WIS: 1-5 Rate of salesfloor preparation ",WIS: Completed pre inventory call to store prior to count? ,WIS: Enough store staff available to answer questions/concerns? ,"WIS: Errors identified during the recheck process? ","WIS: Rechecks completed and copies retained during count? ",WIS: Improvement areas for next count? ,WIS: End time of count? ,WIS: Start time of count?

Here is an example set of data for each header

4586833 ,1/2/2016 6:00:00 PM ,SHOP EASY FOODS #7037 FULL ,355 FRONT STREET ,na ,na ,great job ,5 ,5 ,1 ,Y ,Y ,Y ,na ,great job ,Darryl Krakowka ,Darryl Moe ,Y ,n/a ,none great work! ,5 ,5 ,Y ,Y ,N ,yes ,none great work! ,1/2/2016 9:42:00 PM ,1/2/2016 6:00:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

Before you come to the VBA, I think you should establish that this is the problem first of all by following my recommendation. Once you've proved this, it should be relatively straight forward to use REPLACE to rid yourself of the quotes and erroneous spaces before and after the commas on the header line:

```
Replace(yourString, Chr(34), "")
Replace(yourString, ", ", ",")
Replace(yourString, " ,", ",")
```

Then you just need to format the Access table to match these header fields. As a rule of thumb, using spaces in field names is bad practice.

Comment: The way my employer wants it to be is fully automated in VBA without any manual editing or fiddling, a one-click macro that does it all. Based on your recommendation I have removed all spaces, quotes, etc. that I have found but still have not had success in importing the data correctly.

Comment: If you've done all that, and you've checked that your MS Access fields exactly match the import .CSV, then it's likely you've got some funny "hidden" characters in your CSV file. Try downloading a free application called Notepad++ https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.9.html This will show reveal anything that's throwing off the schema of your import.